# Bypass Outlook Security when sending email via Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, outlook

I've done an automatically Reminder to send emails from Excel, triggered by a VBS file (placed in the StartUp folder). When I open my PC, the reminder is triggered and it should send the email, but i have a security error.

This is the Excel Macro:

```
Sub Email()
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100      
If Cells(i, 3).Value = Date And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 7)) Then  
        Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
        Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        aEmail.Importance = 2
        aEmail.Subject = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4)
        aEmail.Body = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5)
        aEmail.To = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6)
        aEmail.Send
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Sent: " & Now
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This is the VBS file:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
userName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%UserName%" )
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" + userName + "\Desktop\RM.xlsm", 0, False) 
xlApp.Application.Run "Email"
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit 
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
```

**How can I can bypass this error, by adding something more in my macro?**    [image: error]
(I've tried all the codes from google, but none of them work. I also don't want to change nothing on Outlook Settings or Windows Reg.)

Comment: Install & use the Redemption objects http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

Comment: which version of Outlook?

Comment: I have Outlook 2013.

Comment: In order to avoid that warning, you will need to either change Outlook security settings, or change a Registry value, or use a 3rd party application/plug (which would also be changing Outlook's settings in the registry}.  You cannot avoid the warning by adding more code, otherwise the warning would have purpose it the first place. That's like wanting code to bypass a virus scanner.  If it were possible, virus scanners would never catch viruses.  Generally, it's a bad idea to bypass security settings on "anything"; they are there for a reason.  The problem is that you're using a VBS.

Comment: You can avoid Outlook all together with Microsoft Collaboration Data Objects (CDO). http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/cdo.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Install up-to-date antivirus software (Outlook will not display a prompt then) if you can control the environment where your code runs
2. Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi, does not apply in case of VB script). You can however use a wrapper like [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) that uses Extended MAPI but is accessible from any language including VBS.
3. A product like [ClickYes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/).

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for a discussion and a list of available options.

Comment: It works now. I have a up-to-date antivirus software, the problem was with the macro on startup. I added a delay in the VBS file with 
WScript.Sleep 180000 (3 minutes) and now it have enough time to check the antivirus status.

Answer (score 0):

Try again after updating antivirus security.

[image]